# A macros in the C language (#define)

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am reading source code of hoard memory allocator, and in the file of gnuwrapper.cpp, there is the following code

```
#define CUSTOM_MALLOC(x)     CUSTOM_PREFIX(malloc)(x)
```

What's the meaning of `CUSTOM_PREFIX(malloc)(x)`?  is  `CUSTOM_PREFIX` a function? But as a function it didn't defined anywhere. If it's variable, then how can we use variable like `var(malloc)(x)`?

More code:

```
#ifndef __GNUC__
#error "This file requires the GNU compiler."
#endif

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


#ifndef CUSTOM_PREFIX   ==> here looks like it's a variable, so if it doesn't define, then define here.
#define CUSTOM_PREFIX
#endif

#define CUSTOM_MALLOC(x)     CUSTOM_PREFIX(malloc)(x)    ===> what's the meaning of this?
#define CUSTOM_FREE(x)       CUSTOM_PREFIX(free)(x)
#define CUSTOM_REALLOC(x,y)  CUSTOM_PREFIX(realloc)(x,y)
#define CUSTOM_MEMALIGN(x,y) CUSTOM_PREFIX(memalign)(x,y)
```

Comment: The angle brackets will show up just fine in code and text if you format the code with the 1010 button above the text entry area.

Comment: thanks a lot for Neil. stackoverflow is so cool, lots of people are ready to help others, it's amazing that my question got answered in several minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, since CUSTOM_PREFIX is defined to be nothing, the string `CUSTOM_PREFIX(malloc)(x)` will expand to

```
(malloc)(x)
```

which is equivalent to the usual

```
malloc(x)
```

However, the CUSTOM_PREFIX allows the developer to choose a different memory management function. For example, if we define

```
#define CUSTOM_PREFIX(f) my_##f
```

then `CUSTOM_PREFIX(malloc)(x)` will be expanded to

```
my_malloc(x)
```

Comment: actually, `(malloc)(x)` is not equivalent to `malloc(x)`: the former is guaranteed to be a function call, whereas the latter might be a macro invocation (see C99 7.1.4 §5 for an example showing the different ways to invoke standard lib functions)

Answer (score 0):

`CUSTOM_PREFIX` is defined as nothing, so it will just disappear, leaving behind `(malloc)(x)`, which is the same as `malloc(x)`. Why? I don't know. Perhaps other places in the code set `CUSTOM_PREFIX` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, its a macro which changes calls to malloc(x) etc. into something like:

```
DEBUG_malloc( x );
```

You can choose to supply the macro yourself, to provide  a customised prefix for the functions, or not in which case the names won't be changed.