# Question about a wrapper macro function

Tags: c, macros

I was reading the jemalloc's realloc function and noticed that all the non-static functions(at least the ones I've seen) in jemalloc is wrapped with JEMALLOC_P macro and JEMALLOC_P is:

`#define JEMALLOC_P(s) s`

Why would they need such a thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [a macro question for c language (#define)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887406/a-macro-question-for-c-language-define)

Comment: Hello Kenny,
I think they aren't duplicates, in the question that you have sent they are discussing what the macro is doing. Here I know what the macro is doing. But i'm questioning about why did they write in this way. For example, is this for optimization?

Comment: This `JEMALLOC_P` is doing the exact same thing (in spirit) as `CUSTOM_PREFIX` in the link.

Comment: @kenny ok how should close or delete this question then?

Comment: You can't delete it since someone has already answered it. To close it 3 more people need to vote to close. Well, if you fully understand what JEMALLOC_P is doing, you should just provide an answer yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jemalloc `configure` script:

```
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([JEMALLOC_P(string_that_no_one_should_want_to_use_as_a_jemalloc_API_prefix)], [${JEMALLOC_PREFIX}##string_that_no_one_should_want_to_use_as_a_jemalloc_API_prefix])
```

I'd guess that it is intended to provide a prefix for all of the jemalloc functions.

You'll also see things like this in `jemalloc.h`:

```
void *JEMALLOC_P(malloc)(size_t size)
```

So, by default, jemalloc takes over the `malloc()` name but if you need to still use plain `malloc()` then you could

```
#define JEMALLOC_P(s) je_##s
```

and get `je_malloc()` and plain `malloc()` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the context that line is in. The code is actually:

```
#ifndef JEMALLOC_P
#  define JEMALLOC_P(s) s
#endif
```

This means that, prior to including the header file, you could have provided your version of the `JEMALLOC_P()`. If you haven't that is the default.

Comment: Yes I know what it means. And they don't redefine JEMALLOC_P in any other place of the code. So I assumed that they are using #  define JEMALLOC_P(s) s as default. But why the hell they are using this? AFAIK it doesn't change anything in the code? it just takes a function and return it back.